# How do i display certain images based on a variables value?

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I have managed to display an image when a variable reaches a value above 12, but lets say the variable reaches a value over 20- what if i then want a different image to be displayed? I have experimented with "else" but it dosen't seem to work- does anyone have an idea?

```js
var poeng = 0;
var imgURL = 'https://partycity6.scene7.com/is/image/PartyCity/_pdp_sq_?$_1000x1000_$&$product=PartyCity/278696';
function createImage(url) {
  var imgEl = document.createElement('img');
  imgEl.alt = 'Nerd';
  imgEl.src = url;
  return imgEl;
}

function myFunction() {
  poeng = 5;
  console.log(poeng)
  check()
}

function myFunction2() {
  poeng = 7;
  console.log(poeng)
  check()
}

function myFunction3() {
  poeng = poeng + 5;
  console.log(poeng)
  check()
}

function check() {
  if (poeng > 12) {
    var imgEl = createImage(imgURL);
    document.body.appendChild(imgEl);
  }
}
poeng = 24
check()
```

Comment: I made you a snippet. Please edit, scroll down to _edit above snippet_ and provide a [mcve] with expected output

Comment: You mean `function check() {
  if (poeng > 12)  imgUrl = "a";
  else if (poeng > 20)  imgUrl = "b";
    var imgEl = createImage(imgURL);
    document.body.appendChild(imgEl);
}`

Comment: It gives me a bug saying "unexpected token"...

Comment: I found out "else" is the unexpected token

Comment: You likely pasted it wrong. You need to put each statement on one line and have semicolons

Comment: Ok! I'll try :)

Answer (score 0):

I believe that to be your scenario

```js
let poeng = 0;

      const images = {
        12: "https://partycity6.scene7.com/is/image/PartyCity/_pdp_sq_?$_1000x1000_$&$product=PartyCity/278696",
        20: "https://partycity6.scene7.com/is/image/PartyCity/_pdp_sq_?$_1000x1000_$&$product=PartyCity/278697",
      };

      function check() {
        poeng++;
        if (poeng > 20) {
          return (document.getElementById("nerd").src = images[20]);
        }
        if (poeng > 12) {
          return (document.getElementById("nerd").src = images[12]);
        }
      }
```

```css
img[src=""] {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="check()">plus one</button>
<img src="" id="nerd" alt="Nerd" />
```